# Firebase web push notification in iframe is only working in firefox

Tags: firefox, firebase, iframe, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using firebase for web push notification it is working perfect when I used it in same domain, but I have only one ssl domain and many non ssl website. So I have plan to use it in iframe and integrate this facility in all my non ssl websites too.


**URL is**

```
https://htmlcodeplay.com/notification/notification/index.html?websiteid=3
```

I have integrate it through iframe like below

```
<iframe src='https://htmlcodeplay.com/notification/notification/index.html?websiteid=3'></iframe>
```

I have integrate this lines into my blogger https://allinworld99.blogspot.in. But it is working perfectly in Firefox browser but not in chrome browser. No errors also displayed. 
As per this link [Does my web application require SSL for Firebase Cloud Messaging for Web to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298292/does-my-web-application-require-ssl-for-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-web-to-work). It should not work, but how it is working in firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to find a reference right now, but you want to do

*embed a "push notification webpage" inside another via iframe*

is blocked by Chrome for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please give me a example?